# How to append a new key and value into a dictionary of lists using a function

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

```
{'Brazil': [19000000, 810000.00], 'Japan': [128000000, 350000.0]}
```

If I have `dict1` which holds data about a country *name*, *population* and *area*, and I want to use a **function** to add a *new* country, population and area in the same format as my current dictionary (where the values are enclosed in a list), how would I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use below code:

```
dict1 = {'Brazil': [19000000, 810000.00], 'Japan': [128000000, 350000.0]} #initial dict

def addToDict(c, p, a):
    #add new values to dict1, here we are adding country(c) as key, [population(p), area(a)] as value.
    dict1[c] = [p, a] #dict[c] = [p,a] <-- [p,a] are values assigned to the key identified-in/new-key in dict1
    return dict1      #optional - I used it just to see the final value.

print (addToDict('India', 1000000000, 10098978.778)) #main call

#result --> {'Brazil': [19000000, 810000.0], 'Japan': [128000000, 350000.0], 'India': [1000000000, 10098978.778]}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the `addNew` function:

```
dict1 = {'Brazil': [19000000, 810000.00], 'Japan': [128000000, 350000.0]}

def addNew(dict, country, population, area):
    dict.update({country: [population, area]})

addNew(dict1, 'countryTest', 200000, 1000.00)

print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
{'Brazil': [19000000, 810000.0], 'Japan': [128000000, 350000.0], 'countryTest': [200000, 1000.0]}
```

Comment: Why must we pass in dict as the argument also, if say, its defined above the function?

Comment: I just think it is more general. For example, if your define `dict2`, then you can pass it as the argument to the function and update it.

Answer (score 0):

```
pop = 10
area = 20
name = "A"
dict1[name] = [pop, area]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {}

def appendDict(country, population, area):
    dict1[country] = [population, area]

appendDict("Brazil", "19000000", "810000.00")
appendDict("Japan", "128000000", "350000.0")

print(dict1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example:

```
travel_log = [
{
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 12,
  "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"]
},
{
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 5,
  "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"]
},
]

dict1 = {}
def add_new_country(country,visits,cities):
  dict1 = {}
  dict1['country']= country
  dict1['visits'] = visits
  dict1['cities'] = cities
  travel_log.append(dict1)

add_new_country("Russia", 2, ["Moscow", "Saint Petersburg"])
print(travel_log)
```